# Use a more accurate array of x values to generate line of best fit in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am currently stuck on a problem on which I am required to generate a curve of best fit which I am required to use a more precise x array from 250 to 100 in steps of 10. Here is my code below so far..

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import polyfit, polyval
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [250,300,350,400,450,500,550,600,700,750,800,900,1000]
x = np.array(x)
y = [0.791, 0.846, 0.895, 0.939, 0.978, 1.014, 1.046, 1.075, 1.102, 1.148, 1.169, 1.204, 1.234]
y= np.array(y)

r = polyfit(x,y,3)
fit = polyval(r, x)

plt.plot(x, fit, 'b')
plt.plot(x,y, color = 'r', marker = 'x')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to create an array of numbers from a to b by steps of c.

With pure python you can use:

```
list(range(a, b, c)) #in your case list(range(250, 1000, 10))
```

Or, since you are using numpy you can directly make the numpy array:

```
np.arange(a, b, c)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array in steps you can use `numpy.arange([start,] stop[, step])`:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(250,1000,10)
```

Comment: How would I generate a line of best fit with the new x array since the original amount of values in x was 13 and now we got 75.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correctly: You don't have more `y` data points so it's not possible to fit with more `x` values? Do you actually only want to *plot* your new function with more `x` values?

Comment: The question is very confusing to me too... it says: "Plot the best curve fit of either degree 1 (straight line), degree 2, or degree 3 along with the measurement markers (use the numpy functions polyfit and polyval). To determine the best fit, evaluate the three polynomial models starting from degree 1 up to degree 3. (Put comments in your code describing which one produces the best fit.) Use a finer list of x values (250 to 1000 steps of 10) to compute the polyfit "

Comment: This is indeed a very weird question, if the `y` values were the only ones provided. Of course you can always *plot* with more `x` values, but that does not change the accuracy of the fit.

Comment: Yeah I tried it out on my graphing calculator and nothing changed about the fit.... But I figured out how to do it now lol

Comment: Yes there is no way the fit will change if you use the same set of data :D

Answer (score 0):

To generate values from 250-1000, use range(start, stop, step):

```
x = range(250,1001,10)
x = np.array(x)
```